# I'm unable to retrieve title attribute text of 2nd search result from a search result list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get title text "Interactions/Rant & Rave Survey Scores/CSS Call Volumes" from the below set of code:

```
<div id="$searchResults_children" class="treeChildContainer" style="margin-left: 0px; display: block;">
    <div id="$InteractionsAHT Call FactsTransfer Attempts" class="treeNode" style="display: block;">
        <span class="masterTreeLine treeLine" style="display: block;">
            <img id="$InteractionsAHT Call FactsTransfer Attempts_disclosure" src="res/v-0YH2UYTNo3k/s_Alta/uicomponents/obips.Tree/disclosure_collapsed.png" alt="" class="treeNodeDisclosure" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <span id="$InteractionsAHT Call FactsTransfer Attempts_details" class="treeNodeDetails" title="Interactions/Inbound Call Facts/AHT Call Facts">
                <img src="res/v-0YH2UYTNo3k/s_Alta/uicomponents/obips.Tree/measure.png" alt="" class="treeNodeIcon">
                <span class="treeNodeText">Transfer Attempts</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div id="$InteractionsAHT Call FactsTransfer Attempts_children" class="treeChildContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="$InteractionsCSS Call VolumesTransfer %" class="treeNode" style="display: block;">
        <span class="masterTreeLine treeLine" style="display: block;">
            <img id="$InteractionsCSS Call VolumesTransfer %_disclosure" src="res/v-0YH2UYTNo3k/s_Alta/uicomponents/obips.Tree/disclosure_collapsed.png" alt="" class="treeNodeDisclosure" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <span id="$InteractionsCSS Call VolumesTransfer %_details" class="treeNodeDetails" title="Interactions/Rant & Rave Survey Scores/CSS Call Volumes">
                <img src="res/v-0YH2UYTNo3k/s_Alta/uicomponents/obips.Tree/measure.png" alt="" class="treeNodeIcon">
                <span class="treeNodeText masterTreeLineSelected treeLineSelected masterTreeLineActive treeLineActive treeNodeFocusClass">Transfer %</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div id="$InteractionsCSS Call VolumesTransfer %_children" class="treeChildContainer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code:

```
List<WebElement> searchResults = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='$searchResults_children']/div"));

for (WebElement searchResult : searchResults) {
    String item = searchResult.getText();

    if (item.equals(searchItemName)) {

        WebElement tooltip = searchResult.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='$searchResults_children']/div[@class='treeNode']/span[@class='masterTreeLine treeLine']/span[@class='treeNodeDetails']"));

        String tooltipName = tooltip.getAttribute("title");

        System.out.println("Mertic: " + item + "\nTooltip: "+ tooltipName);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to retrieve is the title text "Interactions/Rant & Rave Survey Scores/CSS Call Volumes" which is the second search result. But I'm getting the title from the first result.

I was thinking since I'm using the search result to find the next element it should hold one search item at a time but that's not the case here.

Please suggest.

Comment: you're doing everything right as far selenium goes. I tested your code in c# and it worked fine but you're not using C#. It may be a matter of the slash acting like a delimiter or something. What is the value of tooltipName?

Comment: IMO, majority of the `id` seems to me as dynamically generated id. Hence you may not be able to match the nodes using `id` as `$searchResults_children`.

Comment: @chris-crush-code the value I'm getting for tooltipName is "Interactions"

Comment: @DebanjanB the id $searchResults_children is static for any search result. And after that div node with id $searchResults_children everything is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

`/` is having a special reference in java. May be it was causing issue.

I haven't tried but try below code, it may help :

```
String test[];
List<WebElement> searchResults = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='$searchResults_children']/div"));

for (WebElement searchResult : searchResults)
{
    String item = searchResult.getText();
    WebElement tooltip =searchResult.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='treeNode']/span/span"));
    test = tooltip.getText().split("/");
    for (String searchResult1 : test) 
    {

        System.out.println(searchResult);
    }
    String tooltipName = tooltip.getAttribute("title");
    System.out.println("Mertic: "+item+", Tooltip: "+tooltipName);
}
```

Comment: sorry...couldn't understand what was the 'for loop' for. That is not being used anywhere. Am I missing something ?

Comment: inside loop print after spliting the values from "/" .. if it work then I can tell you further improvement.. are you able to get all values

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WebElement tooltip =searchResult.findElement(By.xpath("/div[@class='treeNode']/span/span"));
```

Since you are looking for the direct child `div/div/span/span`

Also do you need to loop through all the elements/children of the outer element "div"? if not then you can use hirarchy with all elements till the span (if there is no risk of changing this hirarchy in future)

Comment: no this doesn't work...I also was trying this only but I don't know why it was picking something else from the page. I was of the opinion that it should be constraint to my particular search result div and would give me the required value.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to get the `title` attribute of this element

```
<span id="$InteractionsAHT Call FactsTransfer Attempts_details" class="treeNodeDetails" title="Interactions/Inbound Call Facts/AHT Call Facts">
```

It has an ID so we can use that to locate it and then pull the `title` attribute.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[id$='Attempts_details']")).getAttribute("title");
```

This locator looks for a `SPAN` that has an ID that ends with (`$`) `Attempts_details`. We could just specify the entire ID but it's long and this substring is unique, at least with the HTML provided.

---

I was making the assumption that you were getting the wrong element, thus an incomplete title. I'm guessing that it has something to do with writing it to the console? It should work because there is no special significance to the forward slash. Have you tried writing it to a text file or put a break point on that line and looking at what the variable contains?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment that `the id $searchResults_children is static for any search result` the following code block would retrieve the text **Interactions/Inbound Call Facts/AHT Call Facts** from the desired node:

```
String my_string = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='$searchResults_children']/div[@class='treeNode'][contains(@id, 'FactsTransfer Attempts')]/span[@class='masterTreeLine treeLine']//span[@class='treeNodeDetails']")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(my_string);
```

Comment: I tried this but its fetching some other element from the page. Also I just figured out that there is no issue with the forward slash, its only that my xpath (the one you suggested as well) is pointing to some other element from the page

Comment: I have extensively used the parent node attribute `@id='$searchResults_children'` which you mentioned as static and have climbed down the child nodes so that we can reach to the exact node. Now as you mentioned `xpath (the one you suggested as well) is pointing to some other element ` essentially means the `HTML DOM` we are referring is not the exact one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that there are multiple div nodes containing different search results. all these nodes are under  the div node with
    @id='$searchResults_children'
I have put the html for one of them

Comment: Great !!! So that essentially means that `@id='$searchResults_children'` is static but its not `unique`, its **dynamic**. Hence we need dynamic `xpath` or `css`.

Comment: I need to fetch the tooltip only if the item content matches to my searchItem

Comment: But you need to get hold of the node first which contains the text(). For that we need the exact HTML DOM.

Comment: I've updated the question with all the search result. Can you please look into it ?

Comment: I wanted to fetch "Interactions/Rant & Rave Survey Scores/CSS Call Volumes" and I cant make the code static. I have to try to create a code block which can be reused for different searches.

Thank you very much...you help means a lot

Comment: I've accepted the answer as it solves the query but its not what I wanted. It making the xpath static. If I would have wanted that I could have used `//div[@id='$searchResults_children']/div[2]/span/span`

Comment: I think as per best programming practice `xpath` shouldn't contain indexes. Thanks and All the best.